# Sonarqube won't upgrade to 5.1.x after incompatible plugins have been uninstalled

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1

I uninstalled the "violation filter" before this upgrade attempt, but to no avail :(

Looks like there are still ViolationFilter parts left in the database that block the update and are not disabled or removed by uninstalling the plugin. There are no plugins installed that are marked incompatible with 5.1.x

I tried to up from 5.0.1 to 5.1.1

```
2015.06.15 08:50:36 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  AddUuidToAnalysisReports: migrated (0.0960s) ==============================
2015.06.15 08:50:36 INFO  web[DbMigration]
2015.06.15 08:50:36 INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector] Initializing Hibernate
2015.06.15 08:50:38 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database
org/sonar/api/rules/ViolationFilter
        java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
```

**update:** These plugins are currently installed:

```
PLUGIN       | VERSION | DESCRIPTION
------------ | ------- | ----------------------------------------------------------
Checkstyle   |     2.3 | Analyze Java code with Checkstyle.
Cobertura    |   1.6.3 | Get code coverage with Cobertura.
fb-contrib   |     1.3 | New Findbugs rules (see http://fb-contrib.sourceforge.net)
Findbugs     |     3.2 | Analyze Java code with Findbugs 3.0.1.
Java         |     3.3 | SonarQube rule engine.
PMD          |   2.4.1 | Analyze Java code with PMD.
Tab Metrics  |   1.4.1 | Add a new tab containing metrics information at file level
Widget Lab   |     1.6 | Additional widgets
```

Note that Widget Lab version 1.7 has been set to load in 5.1.1

Comment: Can you please update your question to give the list of installed plugins and their versions please?

Comment: fb-contrib is now packaged with Findbugs plugin (see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Findbugs+Plugin), so it should be uninstalled.

Comment: please let us know what steps you have performed to remove the violation filter plugin. have you restarted your sonar after this event.

Comment: After uninstalling fb-contrib and starting all from scratch, I am now up and running 5.1.1.
I suspect that a previous plugin jar was stuck in the new environment and got picked up. Thanks for the hints and help.

Comment: @Tux I added the answer to your question below so that you can validate it - because this can be valuable for other users. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Simon, the fb-contrib plugin is not compatible with latest versions of SonarQube and therefore it should be removed.

For your information, fb-contrib is now packaged with the [Findbugs plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Findbugs+Plugin).